# How does Yahoo Mail make the back button traverse through previous clicks in their UI?

Tags: ajax, browser, iframe, gmail, yahoo-mail

Try the following case:

1. Log on to Yahoo Mail.
2. Click Inbox.
3. Click Drafts.
4. Click Sent.
5. Click Spam.
6. Click Trash.
7. Observe the browser's back history menu -- these different "pages" are not listed.
8. Now click back button multiple times-- the browser cycles through each of previously clicked "pages". (Note that "Forward" button is not available though...)

Finally, click logout. Now click back button .. none of the "pages" are in cache.

How does Yahoo do this? It seems like they are manipulating the use of the Back button.

Would appreciate an analysis of this since I would like to implement similar functionality.

Comment: you could check their javascript.

Comment: How is this related to Gmail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They probably use their own [Browser History Manager](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/history/) (the source is on [github](http://github.com/yui/yui2/blob/master/build/history/history.js))

Answer (score 0):

That is **Ajax Back button** functionality..

Check this example

**http://mark.netmegs.com/bbfix/uptime.html**

Comment: Your example appears different than yahoo mail. In that example, the page reloads on each button click. Entries are added to the history menu. That is not the case with yahoo mail.